# SVM in Point Cloud Library

Tags: svm, point-cloud-library

Does anyone know the difference between:
pcl/ml/svm.h VS pcl/ml/svm_wrapper.h

Also does anyone know if there is a official tutorial for this build in SVM lib?
I tried to search a lot but could not find anything except forum threads.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking at this svm_wrapper.h includes the svm.h. I am not sure why it has this structure. I found a semi-tutorial [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/ml/include/pcl/ml/svm_wrapper.h).